# Reassigning @State works exactly once

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm working on a SwiftUI app and having some weird behavior around a `@State` property. I'll lay out the architecture...

```
struct Video {
    ...
}

class VideoLibrary: ObservableObject { 
    @Published var videos: [Video]
}

struct VideoList: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var videoLibrary: VideoLibrary

    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination:
            VideoDetail(
                video: videoLibrary.videos[0]
            )
        ) {
            Text("The Video")
        }      
    }
}

struct VideoDetail: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var videoLibrary: VideoLibrary
    @State private var videoUrl: String? = nil
    @State private var videoPlayerPresented: Bool = false
    @State var video: Video

    var body: some View {
        Button {
            Task.init(priority: TaskPriority.high) {
                // This is an endpoint that fetches the token for the video url
                if let token = try await videoLibrary.signVideo(video: video) {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.videoUrl = "\(video.url)?token=\(token)"
                        self.videoPlayerPresented = true
                    }
                }
            } label: {
                Text("Play Video")
            }
            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: self.$videoPlayerPresented) {
                VideoPlayer(urlString: self.$videoUrl)
            }
        }
    }
    .onAppear {
        Task.init(priority: TaskPriority.high) {
            // This is an endpoint that fetches the video with url
            if let video = try await videoLibrary.fetchVideoStreamInfo(videoId: video.id) {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.video = video
                }
            }
        }
    }    
}

struct VideoPlayerView: View {
    
    @Binding var urlString: String?
    
    var body: some View {
        // An AVKit VideoPlayer, it works the first time, just focuing on SwiftUI State and Bindings
        VideoPlayer(...)
    }
}
```

1. On launch the app loads in videos to `VideoLibrary`

   - There's really a `LazyVGrid` of videos, but I just show one here. Pretty sure this isn't the issue
2. I pass the video into `VideoDetail`, where it is annotated with `@State`

   - I read that `@State` properties should really be `private` to drive home their `@State`-iness.
   - The video property is not `private` because it comes in through init.
3. When `VideoDetail` appears, I fetch the video again on a different endpoint because the one I get passed doesn't have a url (by design :eyeroll:).

   - I "replace" my video with the one from the server. I don't care about updating the `VideoLibrary` version.
   - The video property cannot be a non-`@State` var because VideoDetail is a struct and immutable. Annotating as `@State` allow me to do this.
4. When you select "Play Video", I have to fetch the token for the url.

   - When going through the flow the first time, my video property has a now fetched url. I am able to tokenize it, update the videoUrl property and the video plays. So it works great!
   - Going back to `VideoList` and choosing another video, my video loads its url, but when then fetching the token the url has now disappeared on the video object. `self.video = video` is not occurring the *second* time.
   - The `@State` videoUrl is a `@Binding` in `VideoPlayerView` and automagically gets updated.

I am guessing that it's a bad architecture to take Video object as a parameter, have it annotated as `@State`, replace it, and expect everything downstream to "just work". But I'm not sure what I *should* be doing. I have a lot of non-SwiftUI Swift experience and lots of React experience if that explains my mindset.

Comment: hard to say since this isn't runnable code, but my instinct is to say that having a `Video` that must be updated after the `videoLibrary.fetchVideoStreamInfo` call probably isn't the way to go. How about storing the stream info separately?

Comment: Thanks @jnpdx, I removed `@State` from the video param and added another `@State` video property which I use after the second load and it works. I'm moving forward with that for now, but still curious what the SwiftUI expects here.